# Problem with "Lighting" in Mathematica V9

Tags: graphics3d

I am showing two figures with Show:

```
a = ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {1, 0, 3}, {1, 1, 3}, {0.25, 
 0.5, 1}, {0.75, 0.5, 1}}];
b = ListLinePlot[{0, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9}];
c = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Texture[b], Blue, 
 Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}},
Axes -> True];
Show[{c, a}]
```

Now, because I want the background of b to be white, I do :

```
d = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Texture[b], Blue, 
 Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
  VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}},
Lighting -> "Neutral", Axes -> True];
```

But when I do

```
 Show[{d, a}]
```

the figure a also becomes white. How can I solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the 2D figure retain its own colors, independently of the 3D lighting, you could add [`Glow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Glow.html) to the 2D figure. This doesn't add any transparency to the image, and from the question I concluded that you're not really looking for transparency:

```
a = ListPlot3D[{{0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {1, 0, 3}, {1, 1, 3}, {0.25, 
     0.5, 1}, {0.75, 0.5, 1}}];
b = ListLinePlot[{0, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9}];
c = Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[], {Glow[White], Texture[b], Blue, 
     Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
      VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}},
    Axes -> True];
Show[{c, a}]
```

[image: glow]

Comment: Thank you very much, this works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is make the 2D plot background transparent:

```
b = ImageData@Rasterize[ListLinePlot[{0, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9}], Background -> None];
```

Then you don't have to have to worry about lighting:

```
Show[{c, a}]
```

[image: Tranpsarent2D]

Comment: thank you. It does the job. But there is a problem with the resolution of b. Can you increase the resolution? I tried adding Raterize->2000 but it did not work.

Comment: You can use `RasterSize -> 2000` as an option in `Rasterize`.  But it still doesn't look that flash.  Jens' solution looks better.

Answer (score 1):

Setting the lighting in `a` and then showing `a` and `d` in the order `a` first (order matters) does what I think you want in V10.1. No sure if it will work in V9, but I think it might.

```
a = 
  ListPlot3D[{
    {0, 0, 3}, {0, 1, 3}, {1, 0, 3}, {1, 1, 3}, {0.25, 0.5, 1}, {0.75, 0.5, 1}}, 
    PlotStyle -> White,
    Lighting -> {{"Ambient", RGBColor[1., 0.85, .25]}}]
```

[image: plot-a]

```
b = ListLinePlot[{0, 4, 2, 7, 4, 9}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]
```

[image: plot-b]

```
d = 
  Graphics3D[{
    EdgeForm[], {Texture[b], 
    Polygon[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}, 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}}];

Show[a, d,
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1},
  PlotRange -> All,
  Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

[image: plot-a-d]